# My image upload going wrong, i get 2 time of imagename.jpeg.jpeg

Tags: php, html, mysql, image

[image: Screen capture of filenames such as images1.jpeg.jpeg]

When I upload an image to the database via **PHP**, *I get a mistake be move to folder* [editor's note: sorry, can't make heads or tails of the preceding - maybe some sort of error message?] and when it moves to the folder, the picture gets post-pended with two extensions: `.jpeg.jpeg`.

Please, I need fast help as it is for my exam and I need to finish this assignment today.

I am using `Class.php`.

The class used can be found here: **https://designpro.be/FileUpload.class.txt**.

**My code:**

```
$_File = new FileUpload($_FILES['image']);

// upload formats JPG, JPEG,PNG
    $_File->addFileType('jpg', array('image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg'));
    $_File->addFileType('jpeg', array('image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg'));
    $_File->addFileType('png', array('image/png'));

    $_nr = rand();
    //$_imgname = $_nr;
    $_imgname = $_nr.$_FILES['image']['name'];

        $_File->setNewName("$_imgname");    

    $_File->move('../img/trailers');

<label>Image</label>
<input type='file' name='image' id='image'>
```

Comment: Are you asking us to read through over 500 lines of code (the linked file) to try and understand what's it all about? First of, all relevant code needs to be added to the question (copy/paste). If the URL changes/the file is removed, this question won't help any future visitors.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i just ask how to upload to folder like in database because wheen it move to folder it ads automatic the second .jpeg to the file

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that it's the class you've linked to that does that (since that's all you're using). You need to narrow down where/when the issue occurs (basic debugging) and show us the _relevant_ parts. Don't just include a ton of code and ask us to debug/narrow it down for you. If it's for an exam, you should know how to debug your code.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson did you know maybe other example for uploadin image and rename before upload?

Comment: Have you tried google? There are literally thousands of tutorials about file uploads using PHP. Asking for off site resources is actually off topic here on SO since it usually leads to opinion based answers.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i am doing that